# Bluebird Promise with Swagger: return is not a function

Tags: javascript, promise, swagger, bluebird

I'm using Swagger to create my JS API client for calling a set of REST endpoints.  I'm configuring the Swagger client to use Promises (`new Swagger({ spec: spec, usePromise: true })`).

I `require` Bluebird before Swagger, to use Bluebird promises.  But my app is blowing up when trying to use `Promise.return`.

The code looks like

```
client.user.get_db_user(db).return("foo");
```

where client is the Swagger reference.

The error I get is

```
app: TypeError: client.user.get_db_user(...).return is not a function
```

It works if I replace `return` with `then(() => value)`.  `return` is supposed to be shorthand for this sort of use of `then`.

After investigating, I see it's failing on promises returned by the Swagger client.

What's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Swagger uses the Q promise library explicitly under the hood.

Bluebird and Q are partially compatible, so many things work fine. The problem happens when trying to use parts of the Bluebird API that Q doesn't have.

In particular, Bluebird has "return", whereas Q does not.

The easiest answer is to use the `then` construction discussed in the question.

Other possible solutions I have yet to try:

1. Use the "bluebird-q" project to replace Q with Bluebird.
2. promisifyAll Swagger instead of using Swagger's built-in promise support.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that you can tell Swagger to use Bluebird promises.  But, in specific places where you want to use Bluebird's methods, you can "cast" a Swagger promise to a Bluebird promise and then use Bluebird's features.  To convert a promise like that, you just wrap it in `Promise.resolve()`:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

Promise.resolve(client.user.get_db_user(db)).return(...)
```

Although in this specific case, since `.return()` is just there to save you some typing, it isn't really a net savings after you've wrapped the previous promise in `Promise.resolve()`.  But, for more meaningful methods like `.map()` or something like that, it might be more useful.